# Wort oder Redewendung für plötzliches, spontanes Vergessen

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

Auf [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/61535/16833) habe ich heute eine Frage gelesen, in der nach einem englischsprachigen Wort gefragt wird, das für die folgende Situation zutrifft:

> You are talking to an acquaintance when another acquaintance walks by whom you greet. Neither knows the other so you are about to mutually introduce them, but you suddenly realize that you do not remember either of their names!

Eine andere aber ähnliche Situation: Man begegnet jemandem auf der Straße, den man – natürlich mit Namen – grüßen möchte, jedoch kommt einem dieser Name nicht mehr ins Gedächtnis.

Oder noch ein Beispiel: Man wird überraschend und unvorbereitet über simple Dinge befragt, z. B. das Alter seiner Eltern, und – obwohl man das natürlich genauestens weiß – hat man keine Antwort parat.

Mir persönlich gefällt die [(zeitlich) erste Antwort](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61536/16833), die Redensart [**"mind goes blank"**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mind+goes+blank), deren Definition dieser Situation auch schon wirklich nahe kommt.

Wie auch immer, ich habe mir nun überlegt, ob es eigentlich ein Wort oder eine Redewendung im Deutschen gibt, das bzw. die diese Vergesslichkeit ausdrückt? Ich beziehe mich hier speziell auf die gegebenen Situationen und den Ausdruck *mind goes blank* und nicht auf die anderen Antworten auf ELU und deren wortgetreue Übersetzung.

Als Kommentar habe ich auf ELU schon ***Blackout*** vorgeschlagen, was man im Deutschen ja auch sagen kann, aber das Gegenargument von J.R. ist schlagkräftig:

> I supposed blackout could be used in a slang since, but blackout can also refer to events more drastic than "drawing a blank," such as losing consciousness, or alcohol-related loss of memory

Daher finde ich auch in der deutschen Sprache ***Blackout*** oder ***einen Filmriss haben*** (auch typisch für Alkoholkonsum) keine gute Wahl.

Ein weiteres Wort, das mir spontan in den Sinn kam, ***Gedächtnislücke***, finde ich ebenfalls unpassend. Am besten gefällt mir noch ***Ladehemmung***, stellt mich aber auch nicht zufrieden.

---

Um es nochmal klarzustellen: Es geht hierbei nicht um ein Wort, das Vergesslichkeit an sich ausdrückt, sondern ausschließlich um eine Beschreibung des unerwarteten, plötzlichen Fehlens einer Information.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jetzt wollte ich etwas antworten, aber leider habe ich gerade einen [**Aussetzer**](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Aussetzer).

Comment: Ach, wie ärgerlich :D. Vllt fällt es dir wieder ein. ^^

Answer (score 25):

In solchen Situationen benutze ich

> **es liegt mir auf der Zunge** (wenn ich meine, es wird mir gleich noch einfallen)
>   **es ist mir entfallen** (wenn ich es mal wusste, ich aber sicher bin, dass es mir erst einmal nicht mehr einfallen wird)

Es könnte konkret auf die Situation bezogen auch ein Krankheitsbild gefragt sein, vielleicht **Wortfindungsstörung**:

> Störung der Fähigkeit, ein bestimmtes Wort abzurufen, bei der es zu
>   sogenannten Nullreaktionen, zu zeitlichen Verzögerungen oder
>   fehlerhaftem Abruf (*Paraphasie*) kommt;
>   eine Wortfindungsstörung
>   kann durch sogenannte Umwegstrategien kompensiert werden, wobei
>   anstelle des speziellen Begriffs Umschreibungen, allgemeine Floskeln,
>   Gestik u. a. verwendet werden.

*(Pschyrembel, 261. Auflage)*

Answer (score 11):

> Ich stehe auf der Leitung.

oder, wie Stovner vorschlägt,

> Ich stehe auf dem Schlauch.

Comment: Hat dieser Ausdruck dieselbe Bedeutung wie "Ich stehe auf dem Schlauch"?

Comment: @Stovner Ja. Beides bedeutet schlicht und ergreifend, dass man etw. nicht versteht. Im gegebenen Kontext ist die *Schlauchvariante* zu bevorzugen, da es auch noch die Nebenbedeutung hat, in eine ungünstige Lage zu geraten: *Wenn die diesen Termin jetzt platzen lassen, stehe ich ganz schön auf dem Schlauch*. Btw. kenne ich das mit der Leitung eigentlich als *eine lange Leitung haben*.

Comment: @Em1: Interessant, die ungünstige-Lage-Lesart von "auf dem Schlauch stehen" ist mir neu.

Comment: @Stovner: Danke, guter Hinweis.

Answer (score 6):

> Ich komm gerade nicht drauf

oder

> Eben hab ich's noch gewusst

Persönlich verwende ich

> Sch... Alzhofer!

Answer (score 2):

Möglich sind auch

> *Tut mir leid. Ich hab' totale Mattscheibe!*
>
> *Tut mir leid. Ich ziehe eine Niete.*

Letzteres habe ich mehrmals humoristisch gehört.

Comment: Kannst du mir den Satz in dem Kontext erklären? Habe ich so noch nie gehört und bin auch nicht atm in der Lage die übertragende Bedeutung zu interpretieren. Wie würde ich den Satz in dem Zusammenhang sagen? *"Wie alt sind denn deine Eltern?" - "Vierund..ah ne warte. ... Hm, ich ziehe eine Niete."*??? *"Hallo ... ähm ... Peter, ne Paul. Ach Mist, ich ziehen eine Niete."*???

Comment: Im Kontext wie du meinst, ja, genauso hab ich's gehört.

Comment: Scheint regional zu sein. Zumindest in Süddeutschland habe ich das noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 1):

Mir fällt dazu noch ein:

> Ich habe gerade eine Blockade.

Oder auch:

> Ich habe gerade ein Brett vor'm Kopf.

Comment: *Ein Brett vor dem Kopf* haben, bedeutet aber imho was anderes. Man versteht eine Sache nicht, ist begriffsstutzig. Es geht eher um ein Verständnisproblem oder meinetwegen auch nicht verstehen wollen.

Comment: @em Das ist vermutlich auch die geläufigere Bedeutung, aber ich kenne diese Wendung auch im hier gefragten Kontext von "ich komm' gerade nicht drauf".

Answer (score 0):

Und hier noch:

> Da muss ich passen.

Und:

> Es ist wie weggeweht.